# Slab cache allocate stack of structures without predefined functions

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, stack, kernel-module

I'm writing a module that creates stack in kernel space using kmem_cache_create and kmem_cache_alloc however it doesn't work. Maybe I've done something bad with the pointers or I don't undestand the whole concept of slab allocating. I've shown the code to the classmates and also my laboratory leader, sadly anyone wasn't able to help me.

Here is my code allocating 5 structures on "stack"

```
#include<linux/module.h>
#include<linux/slab.h>
#include<linux/string.h>

static struct example_struct {
    unsigned int id;
    char example_string[10];
    struct example_struct *next;
} *example_struct_pointer;

static struct example_struct *top = NULL;

static struct kmem_cache *example_cachep;

static void example_constructor(void *argument)
{
    static unsigned int id;
    static char test_string[] = "Stack";
    struct example_struct *example = (struct example_struct *)argument;
    example->id = id;
    strcpy(example->example_string,test_string);
    example->next = top;
    top = example;
    id++;
}

void print_example_struct(struct example_struct *example)
{
    pr_notice("Struct id: %u\n",example->id);
    pr_notice("String field content: %s\n",example->example_string);
}

static int __init slabmod_init(void)
{
    example_cachep = kmem_cache_create("example cache", sizeof(struct example_struct),0, SLAB_HWCACHE_ALIGN|SLAB_POISON|SLAB_RED_ZONE, example_constructor);
    if(IS_ERR(example_cachep)) {
        pr_alert("Error creating cache: %ld\n",PTR_ERR(example_cachep));
        return -ENOMEM;
    }

    for(i=1 ; i<6 ; i++)
    {
        printk(KERN_ALERT "i: %d\n",i);
        example_struct_pointer = (struct example_struct *) kmem_cache_alloc(example_cachep,GFP_KERNEL);
        if(IS_ERR(example_struct_pointer)) {
            pr_alert("Error allocating from cache: %ld\n", PTR_ERR(example_struct_pointer));
            kmem_cache_destroy(example_cachep);
            return -ENOMEM;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

static void __exit slabmod_exit(void)
{
    struct example_struct *tmp = example_struct_pointer;
    if(example_cachep) {
        while(example_struct_pointer != NULL) {
            print_example_struct(example_struct_pointer);
            tmp = example_struct_pointer;
            example_struct_pointer = tmp->next;
            kmem_cache_free(example_cachep,tmp);
        }
        kmem_cache_destroy(example_cachep);
    }
}

module_init(slabmod_init);
module_exit(slabmod_exit);

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("kostek888888");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("A module demonstrating use of the slab allocator.");
MODULE_VERSION("1.0");
```

I also have debug version of this code:

```
#include<linux/module.h>
#include<linux/slab.h>
#include<linux/string.h>

static struct example_struct {
    unsigned int id;
    char example_string[10];
    struct example_struct *next;
} *example_struct_pointer;

static struct example_struct *top = NULL;

static struct kmem_cache *example_cachep;

static unsigned int i;

static void example_constructor(void *argument)
{
    static unsigned int id;
    static char test_string[] = "Stack";
    struct example_struct *example = (struct example_struct *)argument;
    example->id = id;
    strcpy(example->example_string,test_string);
    example->next = top;
    top = example;
    id++;
}

void print_example_struct(struct example_struct *example)
{
    pr_notice("Struct id: %u\n",example->id);
    //pr_notice("String field content: %s\n",example->example_string);
    printk(KERN_ALERT "example_struct_pointer: %p\n",example_struct_pointer);
    //printk(KERN_ALERT "top: %p\n",top);
    printk(KERN_ALERT "i: %d\n",i);
    i++;
}

static int __init slabmod_init(void)
{
    example_cachep = kmem_cache_create("example cache", sizeof(struct example_struct),0, SLAB_HWCACHE_ALIGN|SLAB_POISON|SLAB_RED_ZONE, example_constructor);
    if(IS_ERR(example_cachep)) {
        pr_alert("Error creating cache: %ld\n",PTR_ERR(example_cachep));
        return -ENOMEM;
    }

    for(i=1 ; i<6 ; i++)
    {
        printk(KERN_ALERT "i: %d\n",i);
        example_struct_pointer = (struct example_struct *) kmem_cache_alloc(example_cachep,GFP_KERNEL);
        if(IS_ERR(example_struct_pointer)) {
            pr_alert("Error allocating from cache: %ld\n", PTR_ERR(example_struct_pointer));
            kmem_cache_destroy(example_cachep);
            return -ENOMEM;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

static void __exit slabmod_exit(void)
{
    struct example_struct *tmp = example_struct_pointer;
    i = 1;
    if(example_cachep) {
        while(example_struct_pointer != NULL) {
            print_example_struct(example_struct_pointer);
            printk(KERN_ALERT "tmp: %p\n",tmp);
            printk(KERN_ALERT "next: %p / %p\n\n",top->next,*(top->next));
            tmp = example_struct_pointer;
            example_struct_pointer = tmp->next;
            kmem_cache_free(example_cachep,tmp);
        }
            printk(KERN_ALERT "tmp: %p\n",tmp);
            printk(KERN_ALERT "next: %p\n\n",top->next);
            printk(KERN_ALERT "example_struct_pointer: %p\n",example_struct_pointer);
        kmem_cache_destroy(example_cachep);
    }
}

module_init(slabmod_init);
module_exit(slabmod_exit);

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("kostek888888");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("A module demonstrating use of the slab allocator.");
MODULE_VERSION("1.0");
```

In output I'm getting 12 elements in range 0-11 when I only do kmem_cache_alloc 5 times in range 1-5 and also message "Slab cache still has objects".

[Here is screenshot demonstrating words above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TrMJu.jpg)

After that I'm getting Call Trace message so something with memory is wrong. Sometimes it halts whole virtual machine.

I've swapped the pointer in __exit's while loop for "top" pointer to check what it will show - I had 122 elements and same message so that's probably a whole slab (but maybe not whole because of message?). Pointer "next" always has the same value 122 in DEC - is structure 122 bytes wide? Sizeof structure gave me some huge value above 1,000,000 with %d.

Original code which allocates only one structure and works like a charm:

```
#include<linux/module.h>
#include<linux/slab.h>
#include<linux/string.h>

static struct example_struct {
    unsigned int id;
    char example_string[10];
} *example_struct_pointer;

static struct kmem_cache *example_cachep;

static void example_constructor(void *argument)
{
    static unsigned int id;
    static char test_string[] = "Test";
    struct example_struct *example = (struct example_struct *)argument;
    example->id = id;
    strcpy(example->example_string,test_string);
    id++;
}

void print_example_struct(struct example_struct *example)
{
    pr_notice("Example struct id: %u\n",example->id);
    pr_notice("Example string field content: %s\n",example->example_string);
}

static int __init slabmod_init(void)
{
    example_cachep = kmem_cache_create("example cache", sizeof(struct example_struct),0, SLAB_HWCACHE_ALIGN|SLAB_POISON|SLAB_RED_ZONE, example_constructor);
    if(IS_ERR(example_cachep)) {
        pr_alert("Error creating cache: %ld\n",PTR_ERR(example_cachep));
        return -ENOMEM;
    }

    example_struct_pointer = (struct example_struct *) kmem_cache_alloc(example_cachep,GFP_KERNEL);
    if(IS_ERR(example_struct_pointer)) {
        pr_alert("Error allocating form cache: %ld\n", PTR_ERR(example_struct_pointer));
        kmem_cache_destroy(example_cachep);
        return -ENOMEM;
    }

    return 0;
}

static void __exit slabmod_exit(void)
{
    if(example_cachep) {
        if(example_struct_pointer) {
            print_example_struct(example_struct_pointer);
            kmem_cache_free(example_cachep,example_struct_pointer);
        }
        kmem_cache_destroy(example_cachep);
    }
}

module_init(slabmod_init);
module_exit(slabmod_exit);

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("Arkadiusz Chrobot <***>");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("A module demonstrating useing of the slab allocator.");
MODULE_VERSION("1.0");
```

I've checked books like Linux Device Drivers and similar - everywhere is just plain function with example for one element.

I'm using kernel 3.16.0-4-686-pae but in kernel 4.9 situation is the same.

I will be grateful for every response :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **incorrectly** assume that `ctor()` (last argument to the `kmem_cache_create()`) is called *every time* you call `kmem_cache_create()`.

Actually, this callback function is called only for pre-initialize "garbage" memory before an allocator takes control over it.

In this sequence:

1. `kmem_cache_alloc()`, returns pointer *p*.
2. `kmem_cache_free(p)` (assume allocator remains control over *p*).
3. `kmem_cache_alloc()`, returns pointer *p*.

the callback function is **called** only **ONCE**, at the step 1. The allocator assumes that at the step 2 (freeing) the object pointed by *p* is *already in initialized state*, so step 3 doesn't require initialization.

Proper way for implement list with `kmem_cache` would be:

```
static void example_constructor(void *argument)
{
    static unsigned int id;
    static char test_string[] = "Stack";
    struct example_struct *example = (struct example_struct *)argument;
    /*
     *  This only garantee that at any time every element in the stack has unique id.
     * New element may have same id as previously deleted one.
     */
    example->id = id;
    // All elements will have given string.
    strcpy(example->example_string,test_string);
    // Appending into the stack cannot be performed in the constructor.
    // example->next = top;
    // top = example;
    id++;
}

/* Push allocated element into the stack and return that element. */
struct example_struct* push(void)
{
    struct example_struct* example = kmem_cache_alloc(example_cachep,GFP_KERNEL);

    if(example) {
        // Add to the stack here
        example->next = top;
        top = example;
    }

    return example;
}
/* Pop element from the stack and free the element. */
void pop(void)
{
    // Take the first element.
    struct example_struct *example = top;
    // Remove the element from the stack
    top = example->next;
    // In given example re-initialization actions before freeing the element are not needed.
    kmem_cache_free(example_cachep, example);
}

static int __init slabmod_init(void)
{
    ...
    // Test the stack.
    for(i=1 ; i<6 ; i++) {
         printk(KERN_ALERT "i: %d\n",i);
         example_struct_pointer = push();
         if(!example_struct_pointer)) {
             ...
         }
    }
    return 0;
}

static void __exit slabmod_exit(void)
{
    ...
    // Clean the stack
    while(top) pop();
    ...
}
```

Comment: Awesome! I must thank you :) I would like to ask one more question about "static unsigned int id" because it's static and global it's value is 0 but when we alloc elements we get "11, 12, 13, 14, 15" and also when I'm running code on kvm emulated system on my university with 6 disks raid 10 - that's all I know right now - I don't know the cpu configuration probably I'll know it tomorrow) I get results like "15, 14, 58, 12, 57" it can be related to cpu configuration? [The code was similar and it's here](http://pastebin.com/uuEWqrMe) no stack just allocationg 5 elements not related to each other

Comment: Allocator `kmem_cache` may have more "preallocated" elements than you use. Say, on creation it allocates 16 elements (0-15), and give 11-15 by `kmem_cache_alloc()` request. Each allocated element is wrapped into allocator-specific object, which size is very configuration-dependent. Moreover, there are 3 kind of allocators ("slab", "slob", "slub"), each of which has specific allocation logic. That is why you get different ids on different machines. If you want *stable* ids sequence, do not assign (and increment) id in the constructor, instead do that in the `push()` implementation.